# Exchange variable value between Mathematica and Autohotkey script

Tags: interoperability, external-calls

I have a script written with [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) and would like to send some data to and from Mathematica. For now I am using the `CopyToClipboard[]` function in Mathematica which works with the `OnClipboardChange` implemented in Autohotkey. Using this combination I am able to send data from Mathematica to AutoHotkey.

Is there a better solution for sharing variables between these two programs?

Comment: Do you mind posting your current code?  I doubt there is better way really.